# CSS Animations not fully displaying in safari

Tags: cross-browser, css-animations

So I'm new to using CSS animations and thought I'd play around to learn it. I can get everything displayed and working fine in Chrome but I'm having difficulty getting it to display properly if FF and Safari. (In FF the foreground animation doesn't work and in Safari only the rotate works.)

My HTML is basic:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Happy Birthday!</title>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="carebear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="foreground"></div>
    <div class="midground"></div>
    <div class="background"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
    html {
    background: url('bg.jpg') 0 100% repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;

}
.carebear {
    background: url('care3.png')0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 295px;
    height: 274px;
    -webkit-animation: float 1.8s linear infinite both;
    -moz-animation: float 1.8s linear infinite both;
    -o-animation: float 1.8s linear infinite both;
    animation: float 1.8s linear infinite both;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    -o-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes float {
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    25%{-webkit-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(13deg);
        transform: rotate(13deg);
    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes float {
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    25%{-webkit-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(13deg);
        transform: rotate(13deg);
    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes float {
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    25%{-webkit-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(13deg);
        transform: rotate(13deg);
    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }
}
@keyframes float {
    0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    25%{-webkit-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(13deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(13deg);
        transform: rotate(13deg);
    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }
}
.wrapper {
    -webkit-animation: move 10s ease-in-out infinite both;
    -moz-animation: move 10s ease-in-out infinite both;
    -o-animation: move 10s ease-in-out infinite both;
    animation: move 10s ease-in-out infinite both;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 3;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%{-webkit-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -moz-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -o-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        transform: translate(0px 50px);
    }
    25%{-webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    45%(-webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
        -o-transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateY(100px);
    )
    65%{-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);     
    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0%{-webkit-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -moz-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -o-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        transform: translate(0px 50px);
    }
    25%{-webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    45%(-webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
        -o-transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateY(100px);
    )
    65%{-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px); 

    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
    0%{-webkit-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -moz-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -o-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        transform: translate(0px 50px);
    }
    25%{-webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    45%(-webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
        -o-transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateY(100px);
    )
    65%{-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px); 

    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
@keyframes move {
    0%{-webkit-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -moz-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        -o-transform: translate(0px 50px);
        transform: translate(0px 50px);
    }
    25%{-webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50px);
        transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    45%(-webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
        -o-transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateY(100px);
    )
    65%{-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px); 

    }
    75%{-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
}
.foreground, .midground, .background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
.foreground {
  -webkit-animation: parallax_fg linear 10s infinite both;
  -moz-animation: parallax_fg linear 10s infinite both;
  -o-animation: parallax_fg linear 10s infinite both;
  animation: parallax_fg linear 10s infinite both;
  background:  url('cloud-front.png') 0 100% repeat-x;
  z-index: 4;
}
@-webkit-keyframes parallax_fg {  
  100% { background-position-x: -2400px;} 
  0% {background-position-x:  0px; } 
}
@-moz-keyframes parallax_fg {  
  100% { background-position-x: -2400px;} 
  0% {background-position-x:  0px; } 
}
@-o-keyframes parallax_fg {  
  100% { background-position-x: -2400px;} 
  0% {background-position-x:  0px; } 
}
@keyframes parallax_fg {  
  100% { background-position-x: -2400px;} 
  0% {background-position-x:  0px; } 
}
.midground {
    -webkit-animation: parallax_mg linear 20s infinite;
    -moz-animation: parallax_mg linear 20s infinite;
    -o-animation: parallax_mg linear 20s infinite;
    animation: parallax_mg linear 20s infinite;
    background:  url('cloud-middle2.png') 0 100% repeat-x;
    z-index: 2;
}
@-webkit-keyframes parallax_mg {  
  100% { background-position: -2000px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%; } 
}
@-moz-keyframes parallax_mg {  
  100% { background-position: -2000px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%; } 
}
@-o-keyframes parallax_mg {  
  100% { background-position: -2000px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%; } 
}
@keyframes parallax_mg {  
  100% { background-position: -2000px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%; } 
}
.background {
  background-image:
    url('bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: parallax_bg linear 40s infinite;
    -moz-animation: parallax_bg linear 40s infinite;
    -o-animation: parallax_bg linear 40s infinite;
    animation: parallax_bg linear 40s infinite;
    }
@-webkit-keyframes parallax_bg {  
  100% { background-position: -1920px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%;} 
}
@-moz-keyframes parallax_bg {  
  100% { background-position: -1920px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%;} 
}
@-o-keyframes parallax_bg {  
  100% { background-position: -1920px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%;} 
}
@keyframes parallax_bg {  
  100% { background-position: -1920px 100%;} 
  0% {background-position: 0 100%;} 
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add a link to a demo (using an online site like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). This is an enormous amount of CSS to sift through without the benefit of a working demo to refer to.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fYguN/